# Writing if else statement for a T test in R

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? I am not able to get an output, when I try to test it.

```
Ttest<-function(x,y){
    ifelse(shapiro.test(x)$p > 0.05 & shapiro.test(y)$p > 0.05 & var.test(x,y)$p>0.05, 
        t.test(x,y, var.equal=T, na.rm=T), 
        ifelse(shapiro.test(x)$p > 0.05 & shapiro.test(y)$p > 0.05 & var.test(x,y)$p<=0.05, 
            t.test(x,y, var.equal=F, na.rm=T), wilcoxon.test(x,y, na.rm=T)))
            }
```

R output:

```
Ttest(A,B)
logical(0)
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example by providing us with values for A and B.

Comment: What are `A` and `B`?

Comment: A and B are just random data that I generated in R to test this function. A and B (has equal variances and are normalized) To generate this data I used, are A= rnorm(30,30,5) B=rnorm(30, 20,5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure as to the benefit of putting all of that into a function.   Nevertheless, it seems to me that your issue may be with

`var.test(x,y)$p>0.05`

it should be

`var.test(x,y)$p.value>0.05`

you can't get the p value by just doing `$p` with `var.test` like you can with e.g. `shapiro.test`

If I do the following...

```
a<-c(1,3,6,2,4,6,1,4,7,8,4)
b<-c(6,4,7,4,5,7,3,8,6,4,7,8)
Ttest(a,b)
```

your output is

`[[1]] t  -1.836405`

Comment: To elaborate, `$p` only works with `shapiro.test` due to partial matching. The `p` actually matches `p.value` with `shapiro.test`. The problem is that `var.test` returns two elements that start with `p`. Really, it's better to always specify the full name.